# is there a way to get Schema details of all tables in a big query dataset?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I know i can get schema file for a single table but I have a requirement to get json schema files for all tables in a dataset to implement CICD. Please suggest me any ideas or alternatives.

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` will tell you the schema for all the tables in a dataset.

Use as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables